# How to use CARingBuffer class in an iOS (iPhone, iPad) project?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, buffer

I'm currently trying to create an iOS audio project and I need to use the CARingBuffer class available in the Extras/CoreAudio/PublicUtility folder of XCode.
The problem is when I include the CARingBuffer.h in the header of my viewController and I declare a CARingBuffer object, I receive 4 compile errors.

To reproduce my problem it's pretty simple. Just create a new view based application and try to #include "CARingBuffer.h" in the header of your viewController.

Here's the content of my testViewController.h :

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    #include "CARingBuffer.h"

    @interface testViewController : UIViewController {

    }

    @end
```

Here's the content of my testViewController.m :

```
    #import "testViewController.h"

    @implementation testViewController

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [super dealloc];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

    /*
    // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically                                                         from a nib.
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }
    */

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }

    @end
```

Bellow the 4 compile errors located (strangely) in the CARingBuffer according to XCode 4 :

1) Initializer element is not a constant on line :

```
    const UInt32 kGeneralRingTimeBoundsQueueMask = kGeneralRingTimeBoundsQueueSize - 1;
```

2) Expected ';' after top level declarator, Expected '='... or '**atribute**' before 'CARingBuffer' :

```
    class CARingBuffer {
```

3) Initializer element is not a constant on line :

```
    const UInt32 kGeneralRingTimeBoundsQueueMask = kGeneralRingTimeBoundsQueueSize - 1;
```

4) Expected ';' after top level declarator, Expected '='... or '**atribute**' before 'CARingBuffer' :

```
    class CARingBuffer {
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at this [alternative](http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-simple-fast-circular-buffer-implementation-for-audio-processing/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the class that you are including the ring buffer in  to be a .mm file.

This tells the compiler to use objective c++ .

Answer (score 0):

You need change your testViewController.m to testViewController.mm because CARingBuffer is c++ class.
  About how to use it, here is an extend of CARingBuffer : CARingBufferEx

```
//header file
#include "CARingBuffer.h"
class CARingBufferEx : public CARingBuffer {

public:
    CARingBufferEx();
    ~CARingBufferEx();
    CARingBufferError   Store(const AudioBufferList *abl, UInt32 nFrames, SampleTime frameNumber);

    CARingBufferError   Fetch(AudioBufferList *abl, UInt32 nFrames, SampleTime frameNumber);

private:
    SInt64 firstInputSampleTime;
    SInt64 firstOutputSampleTime;
    SInt64 offset;

};

//Class 
#include "CARingBufferEx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

CARingBufferEx::CARingBufferEx():firstInputSampleTime(-1), firstOutputSampleTime(-1), offset(0) {
}
CARingBufferEx::~CARingBufferEx() {

}

CARingBufferError CARingBufferEx::Store(const AudioBufferList *abl, UInt32 nFrames, SampleTime frameNumber) {
    if (firstInputSampleTime < 0) {
        firstInputSampleTime = frameNumber;
        if (firstOutputSampleTime > 0 && offset == 0) {
            offset = firstInputSampleTime - firstOutputSampleTime;
        }
    }
    return CARingBuffer::Store(abl, nFrames, frameNumber);
}

CARingBufferError CARingBufferEx::Fetch(AudioBufferList *abl, UInt32 nFrames, SampleTime frameNumber) {
    if (firstOutputSampleTime < 0) {
        firstOutputSampleTime = frameNumber;
        if (firstInputSampleTime > 0 && offset == 0) {
            offset = firstInputSampleTime - firstOutputSampleTime;
        }
    }
    return CARingBuffer::Fetch(abl, nFrames, frameNumber + offset);
}
```

Usage:

```
  CARingBufferEx*         _musicMixerRingBuffer;
  _musicMixerRingBuffer = new CARingBufferEx();
  _musicMixerRingBuffer->Allocate(2, sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType), 1024 * 50);
  //1024 is length for one package. and 50 means this buffer contains 50 packages at most.

  //store 
  //ioData is AudioBufferList ,inTimeStamp is AudioTimeStamp 
  musicMixerRingBuffer->Store(ioData, inNumberFrames, inTimeStamp->mSampleTime);
  //Fetch
  musicMixerRingBuffer->Fetch(ioData, inNumberFrames, inTimeStamp->mSampleTime);
```